# select best indices from the result of ensemble using mRMR

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I am using the R package mRMRe for feature selection and trying to get the indices of most common feature from the results of ensemble:

```
ensemble <- mRMR.ensemble(data = dd, target_indices = target_idx,solution_count = 5, feature_count = 30)
features_indices = as.data.frame(solutions(ensemble))
```

This give me the below data:

```
MR_1    MR_2    MR_3    MR_4    MR_5
2793    2794    2796    2795    2918
1406    1406    1406    1406    1406
2798    2800    2798    2798    2907
2907    2907    2907    2907    2800
2709    2709    2709    2709    2709
1350    2781    1582    1350    1582
2781    1350    2781    2781    636
2712    2712    2712    2712    2781
636     636     636     636     2779
2067    2067    2067    2067    2712
2328    2328    2357    2357    2067
2357    783     2328    2328    2328
772     2357    772     772     772
```

I want to use some sort of voting logic to select the most frequent index for each row across all columns.

[image]

For example in the above image :

```
1. For the first row there is no match - so select the first one.
2. There are some rows where min occurrence is 2 - so select that one.
3. In case of tie - check if any occurs thrice, if yes select that one, or else from the tied indices select the first occurring one.
```

May be I am making it too complex, but basically I want to select best indices from all the indices for each row from the dataframe.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) { names(which.max(table(x))) })
```

which gives:

```
[1] "2793" "1406" "2798" "2907" "2709" "1350" "2781" "2712" "636"  "2067" "2328" "2328" "772"
```

For each row, the function `table` counts occurrences of each unique element, then we return the name of the element with the maximum number of occurrences (if there is a tie, the first one is selected).